# Windows azure mobile service script

Tags: windows, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

i have problem how to support my request from mobile service in Windows Azure.
Problem:
How can I check, if my respond to client from server have any record or no. I have this, but it didin't work

```
function read(query, user, request) {
if (query.take(recordCount) > 0) {
    request.respond(200, "Exist");
} else {
    request.respond(500, "ERROR");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of looking at the results of the query:

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    request.execute( {success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        request.respond(200, results);
    }, error: function(error) {
        console.log('error: ', error);
        request.respond(500);
    }});

}
```

Inside the success block you can check to make sure results is not empty and reply with a 200 if there are results or 500 if there aren't.  If you don't want to execute the full read query, you could alternatively use the mssql module to execute a custom sql statement (i.e. select count(*) from tablename).

Comment: ,how to check result is not empty?

Comment: Results !== null && results.length != 0

Comment: If the `success` handler is called, then you can assume that results is not null.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Chris suggested, you can also use the `includeTotalCount()` function, along with a `take(0)` (if you only care about the number of results, not the results themselves), to only count the items which would be returned in the query:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    query.includeTotalCount(); // tell me how many items there are
    query.take(0);             // but don't bother returning them
    request.execute({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.totalCount > 0) {
                request.respond(200, { status: 'Item exists' });
            } else {
                request.respond(500, { status: 'ERROR' });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Or if really all you want to know is whether there are any results or not, you can even skip the `includeTotalCount` call, and just force the response to return up to 1 result with a `take(1)` call:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    query.take(1);             // return at most one item
    request.execute({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.respond(200, { status: 'Item exists' });
            } else {
                request.respond(500, { status: 'ERROR' });
            }
        }
    });
}
```